# Covariance calculation in CAPM

Tags: covariance, quantitative-finance

[image]

can someone explain why the professor can remove risk free rate (rf) from the first line and directly go to the second line like that? both covariance will still be the  same?

why covariance of `((return of asset i - return of risk free rate - beta asset i (return of market - return of risk free rate)) , market return)` is equal to covariance of `((return i  - beta asset i (market return -risk free return)), market return)`

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network https://quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Because r_f is deterministic and covariance of a constant and random variable is 0:

> cov(a,X)=0
>   also
>
> cov(a+X,b+Y)=cov(X,Y), if a,b are deterministic and X,Y are random variables

See the properties of covariance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties.
I hope this helps.